# How to obtain checked checkbox values on the serverside in c# from an ajax Http POST using web forms (not MVC)?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, checkbox, webforms

Here's my ajax call:

```
$(function () {

        $("#chkFilter").on("click", "input", function (e) 
        {
            var filterCheckboxes = new Array();
            $("#chkFilter").find("input:checked").each(function () {
                //console.log($(this).val()); //works fine
                filterCheckboxes.push($(this).prop("name") + "=" + $(this).val());
                console.log($(this).prop("name") + "=" + $(this).val());

                //var filterCheckboxes = new Array();
                //for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                //    if (e[i].checked)
                //        filterCheckboxes.push(e[i].value);
                //}
            });
        console.log("calling ajax");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/tools/oppy/Default",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { filterValues: filterCheckboxes }, // using the parameter name
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        });
        });
    });
```

And my server side code:

```
public partial class tools_oppy_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            string checkedBoxes = Request["filterValues"];
            testLabel.Text = checkedBoxes;

        }
```

I'm just trying to obtain the post URL with the appropriate checked values so I can parse it on the server. However, I'm having trouble obtaining the URL. The string checkedBoxes is supposed to hold a query string like name=value&name=value&name.... but when I test it, the testLabel doesn't show anything. I'm using web forms app, not MVC. Also, I'm new to ajax and their behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume that the url in you JQuery call is valid as there is not aspx extension their.

Second, It looks like what you need to do is create a web method and call it from JQuery for example the following is a web method that accept string

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(String input)
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

and you can call it using the same way with your current code just update the url parameter to include the method name

```
url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
```

for more details about web methods and their union with JQuery please check [this article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

**Edited** The following is complete sample
The web method should look like the following one

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(string filterValues)
{
    return filterValues; //This should be updated to return whatever value you need
}
```

The client side part of calling the web method should look like the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Default/GetData",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //I have added this as "contentType" parameter represents the type of data inside the request meanwhile the "data" parameter describes the data inside the response
    data: "{ filterValues:\"" + filterCheckboxes + "\"}", //Note that I have updated the string here also set the name of the parameter similar to the input of the webmethod
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);//You should access the data using the ".d"
    }
});
```

One last thing, If you are using asp.net permanent routing the above code will not work and you should disable it by updating the file "App_Code/RouteConfig.cs" From

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

To

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

And remember to clear browser cache after the above update

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there anyway to do this by just the Request method? Secondly, am I able to debug/add breakpoints to this code so I can step through it in VS?

Comment: @SKY, To post using only the request, you can do it by having a hidden field with the value of filterCheckboxes then you can access that value server side, I have updated my answer to include full example of the Java script and the web method

Comment: Thank you, your post has been extremely helpful. Also, what is "        alert(result.d);//You should access the data using the ".d""?

Comment: In addition, what if I don't want to return a value from the server? Would the WebMethod still be useable if it is public static void?

Comment: You don't have to return a value just make the return void, and ".d" contain the value return from your we method so if you will make it void then this will be empty

Comment: I'm still trying to access the filterValues in the server side and I can't. I tried testing with Response.Write(filterValues) but nothing shows after checking several checkboxes.

Comment: Can you share your code with me both aspx & code behind